# Is CSS text-align: center really deprecated? If so, what's the alternative?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I am not sure if it's a doc bug from MDN but right now [CSS text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) lists `center` along with `left` and `right` as "Deprecated" and "Nonstandard".

[image]

[image]

I know `left` and `right` should be replaced with `start` and `end` but what about `center`? I have try searching the web and SO but cannot find any info regarding deprecation of `text-align: center`. How should I center texts now?

Comment: That article itself refers to the relevant part of CSS Text Module Level 3, and https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text/#text-align-property clearly still lists `center` as a valid option, and doesn't say anything about it being deprecated.

Comment: @CBroe must be a doc bug then. It was modified relatively recent [here](https://github.com/mdn/content/commit/05a463a3bc1af6e1b1e0d6a273582d954ae00ed0) just to add those exact deprecation tags

Comment: it's a mistake for sure, center will never get deprecated

Comment: @TemaniAfif `center` (the tag) is infact deprecated lol. But I know what you mean.

Comment: Most likely a doc bug, I've filed [an issue here](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/32545)